# Looking for docs/explainer on powershell syntax ":Label foreach ($item in $items) { }"

Tags: powershell

So hard to Google this one...

Looking for docs/explainer on the syntax `:Label foreach ($item in $items) { }`

I came across an interesting example in the official docs and I'm trying to wrap my head around some of the concepts used. The example I'm referencing is at the very bottom of the `about_foreach` page (using `Get-Help`) and also online here: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-7.3#:~:text=%3AtokenLoop%20foreach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-7.3#:%7E:text=%3AtokenLoop%20foreach)

The example defines an AST/parser utility for showing info about where functions are defined within a given script file (pretty cool advanced example imo). There are a few concepts in the example that I've seen before and understand the usefulness of, but haven't used personally, like `do`/`until` statements and enumerator methods like `$foreach.MoveNext()`

But it's the first time I've seen the `:myLabel for () {}` syntax which seems to only be relevant to specific expressions like loops, and I'm curious about the usage of this construct (like how/can you reference this label), does anyone here make use of this or know where to find docs/explainer on it?

Thanks in advance !

*Here's the full raw example from the docs in case you like clicking links:*

```powershell
function Get-FunctionPosition {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  [OutputType('FunctionPosition')]
  param(
    [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory,
      ValueFromPipeline, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [Alias('PSPath')]
    [System.String[]]
    $Path
  )

  process {
    try {
      $filesToProcess = if ($_ -is [System.IO.FileSystemInfo]) {
        $_
      } else {
        Get-Item -Path $Path
      }
      $parser = [System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser]
      foreach ($item in $filesToProcess) {
        if ($item.PSIsContainer -or
            $item.Extension -notin @('.ps1', '.psm1')) {
          continue
        }
        $tokens = $errors = $null
        $ast = $parser::ParseFile($item.FullName, ([REF]$tokens),
          ([REF]$errors))
        if ($errors) {
          $msg = "File '{0}' has {1} parser errors." -f $item.FullName,
            $errors.Count
          Write-Warning $msg
        }
        :tokenLoop foreach ($token in $tokens) {
          if ($token.Kind -ne 'Function') {
            continue
          }
          $position = $token.Extent.StartLineNumber
          do {
            if (-not $foreach.MoveNext()) {
              break tokenLoop
            }
            $token = $foreach.Current
          } until ($token.Kind -in @('Generic', 'Identifier'))
          $functionPosition = [pscustomobject]@{
            Name       = $token.Text
            LineNumber = $position
            Path       = $item.FullName
          }
          Add-Member -InputObject $functionPosition `
            -TypeName FunctionPosition -PassThru
        }
      }
    }
    catch {
      throw
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what exactly do you want to know, if you're looking to understand how labels work you should look at [__about_Continue__](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_continue?view=powershell-7.2#using-a-labeled-continue-in-a-loop) (pointing to label example) or [__about_Break__](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_break?view=powershell-7.2#using-a-labeled-break-in-a-loop)

Comment: If you're familiar with `goto` in batch scripts, it's a lot similar to it.

Comment: `break tokenLoop` is a shortcut to break out of the `foreach` loop that is labeled `:tokenLoop`. Otherwise you'd have to use two `break` statements, one for the inner `do{} until()` loop and one for the outer `foreach` loop. For `continue` this works similarly, you may skip both inner and outer loops from within an inner loop.

Comment: Thank you all! the MS docs pages @SantiagoSquarzon gave are exactly what I was hoping to find, details/examples on loop labels. Appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

A label example from Windows Powershell in Action.  Labels don't come up that often.  In your example, it's breaking out of both the do loop and the token loop with the label.

```
# loop label, break out of both loops
$target = 'outer'
:outer while (1) {
  while(1) {
    break $target   # break or continue label
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't realized it was a feature of powershell's `break` statement